# How to change the raster format using QGIS translate?

Tags: qgis, raster, convert

I tried to change a raster format from .tiff to .asc using Qgis's 'translate'.

As a result, I get 3 files[image: as seen in the Image]: a PRJ, XML and a file without extension just a plain file...

What could it be happening? I used the same tool for a bunch of raster previously and it worked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems ok for me.

In the QGIS input form, you have given a file name for the asc file. In most cases, the default file extension will be added, but this dialogue does not do it. I suggest to enter the extension always manually in this input box.

The prj file contains the projection information (same as for shapefiles), while the xml contains other metadata that was stored in the tif, but can not be written in asc format.